# I want to add all sheets to one sheet in excel

Tags: python, excel

I have one excel file with 20 sheets in python. for using leave one out technology I have to add all sheets to one sheet.

How can I use a loop in python for doing this.

Comment: please make sure to write in a relatively proper English (it doesn't have to be perfect) to make sure other users understand your problem. What do you mean by "for using leave one out technology" ?

Comment: please provide us with an example of what you have tried so far and didn't work. Stackoverflow is not a free coding service, rather a platform where you can debug issues you've encountered while coding.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend you to use Python library, which is called `Pandas` for this task.
You may find nice guide how to do it [here](https://medium.com/@srujanjha/merge-worksheets-in-a-workbook-using-python-1ff6185a3700)

Hope, it will be useful.